# Find the 1 non-repeating element in a given array without XOR or Map in O(n)

Tags: data-structures

How can I find the one non repeating element in an array that all other elements appear exactly twice, when I'm not allowed to use a *hash map* or the operator *XOR*?

**In O(n) time complexity**

Examples:

Input

```
arr[] = {14, 1, 14, 4, 12, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3}
```

Output

```
4
```

Comment: Is there a language you're hoping for, or just something generic?

Comment: just a generic algorithm

Comment: would a while loop, and checking count of each item in array while reducing the array sizes not count, unsure what is consider XOR or Map in 0(n). could you give the XOR and Map in so i can understand what you don't want to use.

Comment: It's ok, I have solved it and posted the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to the problem, using this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZneq1PWFkg 
You can get the median in O(n) time, then you can sort all of the numbers which are greater or equal to the median to the right of it and the ones that are less than it, to be on the left in O(n) time. now everything is sorted in a way that everything that's bigger than the median is on the left and bigger is on the right.

Then You search the array once more to see if the median has a twin, if it doesn’t, you’re done that’s your lonely number, if you’ve found the twin on the left side and the index of the median is odd then you take everything that’s on the left side of the median including it (and throw the others away), same for if you’ve found it in the right side. If the medians index is even you take the opposite side that you find the twin on without including the median. You keep doing the same algo from beginning until you’ve found it.

Then you can get T(n) = T(n/2) + Θ(n)

And with masters theorem you get Θ(n).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in java Script then inside a for loop you can check if the first index and the last index of that item are same then return that item else return -1.

```js
function getFirstDistinctNumber() {
  arr = [14, 1, 14, 4, 12, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3];

  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr.indexOf(arr[i]) == arr.lastIndexOf(arr[i])) {
      return arr[i];
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

console.log(getFirstDistinctNumber());
```

And also in java, you can do the same but `lastIndexOf()` is not present for array. so you can do it by creating an array list

```
import java.util.*;

class FindDistinct {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   // create an empty array list with an initial capacity
   ArrayList<Integer> inputList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   // use add() method to add values in the list
   inputList.add(14);
   inputList.add(1);
   inputList.add(14);
   inputList.add(4);
   inputList.add(12);
   inputList.add(2);
   inputList.add(1);
   inputList.add(2);
   inputList.add(3);
   inputList.add(3);

   for(int i=0; i< inputList.size(); i++) {
     if(inputList.indexOf(inputList.get(i)) == inputList.lastIndexOf(inputList.get(i))) {
        System.out.println(inputList.get(i));
        break;
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sorting the array and then using stack, you can find the required element

```
# code is in python
arr = [14, 1, 14, 4, 12, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3,12]

# sort the array
arr = sorted(arr)

# use a stack to find out the required element
stack = []

for ele in arr:
    if len(stack) == 0:
        stack.append(ele)
    elif stack[-1]==ele:
        stack.pop()
    else:
        stack.append(ele)

print(stack[-1]) # item with one occuerence

# output : 4
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a way compute that in O(1) space and O(n log n) time. Simply binary search the value. For a given number `x` count the number of elements that less or equal to `x` - if this value is odd then the number you're looking for is less or equal to `x`, otherwise if it's even, then it's greater.

(technically the running time is O(n log k) where `k` is `max_value - min_value` from the elements in the array, but there's a way to modify it to work in O(n log n) if needed.)

Answer (score 0):

In c++ using O(n) compexity.

```
int arrayUnique(int *arr, int size)
{

int count;
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
count=0;
    for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
    {
        if(i==j){
            continue;
        }
        if(arr[i] == arr[j]){
            count=1;
        }
    }
    if(count==0){
        return arr[i];
    }
 }
```

}